# Cloudinary Widget not showing up in 'next-cloudinary' Next Js 13 (app router)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cloudinary

I want to upload the video using Cloudinary widget but it shows loading screen continuously for minutes

The state of cloudinary widget:

[image]

`UploadVideoModal.tsx`

```js
"use client";

import {  useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { Box, Button, Modal } from "@mui/material";
import { CldUploadButton } from "next-cloudinary";
import { FcVideoFile } from "react-icons/fc";

import { commonModalStyles } from "@/utils/style";

type Props = {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  tourId: string;
  title: string;
};

const UploadVideoModal = ({ onClose, open, tourId, title }: Props) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const handleUpload = useCallback(async (result: any) => {
    console.log(result);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Modal open={open} onClose={onClose}>
      <Box sx={commonModalStyles}>
        <CldUploadButton
          options={{ maxFiles: 1 }}
          onUpload={handleUpload}
          uploadPreset={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_PRESET}
        >
          <Button
            variant="outlined"
            component="label"
            startIcon={<FcVideoFile />}
            color="info"
            disabled={isLoading}
          >
            Upload
          </Button>
        </CldUploadButton>
      </Box>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default UploadVideoModal;
```

Sorry about this silly question but this is my first Stack Overflow question and before many times I have used Cloudinary widget from `next-cloudinary` package but this happens first time.

I want Cloudinary widget to be

[image]

something like this

Answer (score 1):

So I was trying to figure your error out, and after setting up a nextjs app I started reducing your code to the bare minimum. Here is the code:

```
"use client";


import {  useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { CldUploadButton } from "next-cloudinary";


const Page = () => {
  const handleUpload = useCallback(async (result: any) => {
    console.log(result);
  }, []);


  return (
        <CldUploadButton
          options={{ maxFiles: 1 }}
          onUpload={handleUpload}
          uploadPreset={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_PRESET}
        >
        </CldUploadButton>
  );


};
export default Page;
```

So far running this yield the following output:
[image]

Clicking on the Upload text on the corner opened up the upload widget as you had requested:
[image]

Plus, the uploads are working as intended. Since you’ve already said that you’ve used the `next-cloudinary` package before, I don’t think this may be a user error. I’d recommend checking [this support page](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4510239716370-Upload-Widget-not-working-) out that might be able to help you out. Or you could try starting from the bare minimum code and work your way up, adding components one-by-one to get to the root cause.